# CakePHP routing to *controller* of intended *action*

Tags: php, cakephp

Ok, this is a little confusing to explain, but basically, i'm trying to hit something like:
mysite.com/sections/add

generally, that would take you to SectionsController and the 'add' action.  but no, it's throwing an error saying that it's missing AddController.  It's weird because hitting urls like mysite.com/sections and mysite.com/sections/view/1 work just fine.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: First question, do you have an add() method in the SectionsController class? It sounds like you have a mangled route. Can you post your route code?

Comment: Yeah what he said, paste the contents of your routes.php file in /app/config/.

Comment: `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));`
`Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));`
`Router::connect('/thehouse', array('controller' => 'sections', 'action' => 'view',1));`
`CakePlugin::routes();`
`require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';`

ALSO - everything works locally as it should, i just put it up on an iPower host and this is when the problems came up.  Should have mentioned that earlier.  Sorry!

Comment: And yes, there is an add() method in the SectionsController

Comment: For the sake of testing can you add this: `Router::connect('/sections/add', array( 'controller' => 'sections', 'action' => 'add' ) );`

Comment: No dice - same issue comes up

Answer (score 0):

In order to pinpoint the underlying problem:

1. Set your debug level to 2 in `app/Config/core.php` for full error details.
2. Verify that you indeed do have a **public** function called add in your SectionsController.
3. If 1 and 2 are true, try clearing your cache (remove all files under `app/tmp/cache`).
4. Check for any messages in the `app/tmp/logs/error.log` and/or `app/tmp/logs/debug.log` file(s).

Comment: Tried all that, still seeing this in my error.log:
`2012-02-07 19:02:03 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class AddController could not be found.
#0 /path/to/things/public_html/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2012-02-07 19:02:03 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class Cake.generic.cssController could not be found.
#0 /path/to/things/public_html/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}` ... and another about favico.ico

Comment: It would seem like something funny is happening with your .htaccess, like it's not being parsed properly. Do you get the desired content when you open `index.php?url=/sections/add`?